# How to add a label accessory to a sidebar item in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados

I'm building a SwiftUI app for iPad, using the new Sidebar UI introduced with iPadOS 14. Each sidebar item should have a label accessory. Here's how I'm building it, and the corresponding result:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    enum NavigationItem {
        case companies, aapl
    }

    @State private var selection: NavigationItem? = .companies

    var sidebar: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Companies"), tag: NavigationItem.companies, selection: $selection) {
                HStack {
                    Label("Companies", systemImage: "list.bullet")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("6")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .padding(.trailing, 6)
                }
            }
            .tag(NavigationItem.companies)

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Apple Inc"), tag: NavigationItem.aapl, selection: $selection) {
                Label("Apple Inc", systemImage: "circle")
            }
            .tag(NavigationItem.aapl)
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("Menu")
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            sidebar

            Text("Select an item")
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

It works, but the color of the accessory label doesn't change when the item is selected. The label built with `Label` works as expected though.

Is this the correct way to add a label accessory to a sidebar item in SwiftUI, or is there a better way?

Comment: You gave explicit color for it `.foregroundColor(.secondary)`, try to remove that line.

Comment: When I remove the explicit color it changes to white when selected, and uses `.primary`  otherwise. But I would like the standard behavior, which is a slightly lighter shade of gray for the accessory label.